# How to check if a paramter is an instance of `std::vector`? [C++]

Tags: c++, type-assertion

I have a function that takes in a parameter with generic type T. And it will do different things depending on the type of `obj`.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void function(const T& obj)
{
    if constexpr (/* is a vector */) {}
    else if constexpr (/* is an unordered map */) {}
    // ...
    else {}
}
```

So I need to check if the type of `obj` is `vector`, or `unordered_map`, or `unordered_set`, etc.

Anyone knows the answer to this? Thanks!

Comment: Since it looks like every type has different behavior, the easiest solution is probably to have overloads of `function` for each supported type instead. Ex. `template<class T> void function(const std::vector<T>& obj);`.

Comment: *"I have a function that takes in a parameter with generic type T. And it will do different things depending on the type of obj." - thereby completely defeating the very point of a "generic type T".  Consider overloads with specific container types, lest you fall into a function full of spaghetti as more container types are added.

Comment: Reopened. The claimed duplicate is about a completely different issue.

Comment: Don't check. Write overloads. `template <class T> void f(const T&) { ... } template <class T> void f(const std::vector<T>&) { ... }`. Etc.

Comment: Does it do completely different things, or the same thing in different ways? If it does completely different things, then maybe it should be two functions ("sort_vector" and "filter_map"). If it does the same thing in different ways, maybe you can genericize the implementation so it works for both.

Comment: In this case, as `std::vector`, `std::unordered_map`, etc. are clearly distinct types, I agree it could be easier with overloads. But in our company code base, I was able to simplify a lot some core functions like `toPOD`. Previously, that function was written as a bunch of overloaded complicated templates with `std::enable_if_t`, and it is a lot easier in a single function as a sequence of `if constexpr... else if constexpr`. What I particular find powerful in this approach, is that we guarantee that there is no ambiguity, the order of tests discriminates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments. I have written overloads and it is now working perfectly :)